# LinearRegression fitting gives weird prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

Below is my code

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
X = np.array([[1], [2], [3], [4]])
y = np.array([[6],[8], [2], [2]])
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)


print("Next will mine in", reg.predict([[5]]))
```

and respond for value 5 prediction comes to be

```
Next will mine in [[-1.77635684e-15]]
```

I don't get why this highly large negative number?

Comment: It's a very *small* negative. Notice that it is approximately  -0.00000000000000177635684

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very small negative number, close to zero:

```
-0.00000000000000177635684

a_float = 3.14159
formatted_float = "{:.2f}".format(a_float)
```

Comment: how to round it off so that it shows 0 in this case?

Comment: You can simply format the number upon printing. No point in rounding off.

Comment: See updated answer with formatting code